# Unresolved compilation problems: The method is undefined for the type

Tags: java

Me aparece el siguiente error​ al compilar en Eclipse:

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error:
>  Unresolved compilation problems: 
>
>  The method getValor() is undefined for the type Ejercicio6
>  The method mostrarProductoyValor() is undefined for the type Ejercicio6
>
>      at Ejercicio6.main(Ejercicio6.java:55)
> ```

Pero no entiendo a qué se debe. Este es el código:

```
public class productos {

    private String producto;
    private double valor;

    public productos(String p,double v){
        this.producto=p;
        this.valor=v;

    }

    public String getProducto () { 
       return producto;  
    }

    public Double getValor () {
        return valor; 
    }

    public void mostrarProductoyValor() {
        System.out.println ("Nombre del producto: " + getProducto()+" valor: " +  getValor() );
    }


}
```

---

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ejercicio6 extends productos {

    public Ejercicio6(String producto, double valor){
        super(producto,valor);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Ejercicio6 venta1;
        double suma,v;
        String p;
        suma=0;
        ////si fin esta en cero las ventas siguen hasta que cambie a 1
        int fin=0,i;
        i=0;
        Scanner lector=new Scanner(System.in);
        while(fin==0){
            System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre del producto "+(i+1)+":");
            p=lector.next();

            System.out.println("Ingrese el valor del producto "+(i+1)+":");
            v=lector.nextDouble();


            venta1=new Ejercicio6(p,v);
            suma=suma+venta1.getValor();

            venta1.mostrarProductoyValor();

            System.out.println("0 para siguiente venta");
            System.out.println("1 para terminar el dia");


            fin=lector.nextInt();
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println("La utilidad final es de: "+suma);


    }
}
```

Comment: Por favor, explica exactamente qué error te da (error de compilación, excepción -stacktrace y dónde-, resultado incorrecto -qué valor esperas y que valor obtienes-.

Comment: Me Aparece el siguiente erro al compilar: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 The method getValor() is undefined for the type Ejercicio6
 The method mostrarProductoyValor() is undefined for the type Ejercicio6

 at Ejercicio6.main(Ejercicio6.java:55)

Comment: A primera vista parece correcto (`productos` define esos métodos y `Ejercicio6` extiende `productos`), huele más a alguna confusión (has modificado `productos` pero no lo has vuelto a compilar, tienes alguna otra versión de `productos` y es ésa la que estás usando, etc.)

Comment: si ya he revisado y lo raro es que Eclipse parece que no me reconoce el código de esa clase ya que me aparece subrayada en rojo todas las lineas de la clase productos:

Comment: El problema es el import o el paquete definido agregalos a tus clases. Estan en el mismo directorio?

Answer (score -1):

Los métodos de la clase producto  deben estar de la siguiente forma:

```
protected String getProducto () { 
       return producto;  
    }
protected Double getValor () {
    return valor; 
}

protected void mostrarProductoyValor() {
    System.out.println ("Nombre del producto: " + getProducto()+" valor: " +  getValor() );
}
```

El protected se debe usar con los métodos que vas a heredar.

Comment: Al ingresar el codigo que me envias, se compila pero me pide los primeros 2 valores, luego se revienta y me muestra un error en la linea venta1=new Ejercicio6(p,v);

Answer (score -1):

> The method getValor() is undefined for the type Ejercicio6

El método `getValor()` no existe en la clase `Ejercicio6`,  veo que realizas esto y es correcto ya que `Ejercicio6` extiende de la clase `productos`:

```
 Ejercicio6 venta1;
 ...
        venta1=new Ejercicio6(p,v);
        suma=suma+venta1.getValor();
```

El problema debe ser que el paquete o import a la clase productos es incorrecto.

Comment: -1 Alguna razón para ???